# Upgrading glibc

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, glibc

I just read [here](http://www.zeit.de/digital/internet/2016-02/linux-sicherheitsluecke-glibc-open-source) that there is security bug in glibc and that it is already fixed.

I found out, that the actual installed version of glibc can be shown by `ldd --version`. My systems runs version 2.19.

So I want now to upgrade it but I don't know how to do so. (I don't want to upgrade the whole system). I tried to find out which package contains glibc with `apt-cache search glibc`. But there are hundred of packages...

So does anybody know how to find out the package which I need to upgrade to get the new version of glibc?

Comment: did you try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` ?

Comment: Of course I know these automatically updates. But as I described in my question, I am searching for a way to find out which package includes glibc and needs to be upgraded.

Comment: glibc is the package. you could look at `apt-cache search glibc`  then see glibc-source, and do `apt-cache policy  glibc-source` which would tell your upgrade candidate version. Alternatively, you might mean libc6.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As j0h described, I was able to solve my problem. Here is what I have done:

1. I read at Wikipedia about glibc. Glibc (better known as GNU C Library) has a fork for linux which is called libc6. Libc6 is available via apt.
2. Run `apt-get update` to update the database.
3. Use `apt-cache policy libc6` to find out the installed version and the candidate version, whereas the installed version can be also shown with `ldd --version`.
4. Install the new candidate version with `apt-get install libc6`
5. Check the new version again by doing step 3 again to see your success.

Comment: if my candidate is the same as my current would that mean to move further beyond my glibc version it would necessitate an upgrading to ubuntu as a whole?

Comment: @jxramos Yes this could be. Which version of Ubuntu are you running and did you perform the step number two?

Answer (score 0):

For most security updates such as this you should be able to rest easy knowing that if your version of Ubuntu is still actively supported you will automatically receive such important updates.

Check in 'Software & Updates' that you have the correct boxes checked to:

1. Enable you to receive Security Updates
2. Allow regular checking of the Repository
3. Optionally automatically download and install Security Updates

Below is a screenshot showing you the relevant section of 'Software & Updates':

[image]

This screenshot is for Ubuntu 15.1 Wily Werewolf but will be the same through most modern releases of Ubuntu...