# How to upgrade libc6 (glibc) beyond v 2.31 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: package-management, upgrade, glibc

I am using the Stockfish chess engine within some GUI, but yesterday it stopped working. I hadn't changed the engine, nor the interface, but when I tried to run the engine it "terminated with code...", but it didn't output any code. The only thing that could have changed is that I regularly upgrade my packages:
`sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`, and I guess that must have broke it.
I installed the latest Stockfish Version and ran it in the command line, and the output it gives is:

```
./stockfish_21112912_x64_avx2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by ./stockfish_21112912_x64_avx2)
./stockfish_21112912_x64_avx2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by ./stockfish_21112912_x64_avx2)
./stockfish_21112912_x64_avx2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by ./stockfish_21112912_x64_avx2)
```

So I wanted to upgrade GLIBC and I came upon this thread: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/736208/upgrading-glibc]:
"Glibc (better known as GNU C Library) has a fork for linux which is called libc6. Libc6 is available via apt." I ran:
`apt-cache policy libc6`, which gave the output:

```
libc6:
  Installed: 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
  Candidate: 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
  Version table:
 *** 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.31-0ubuntu9 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Which tells me within the "normal" packages 2.31 is the official version for my OS version (Ubuntu 20.04).

So I tried doing it manually:[How to install a libc6 version >= 2.29?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143268/how-to-install-a-libc6-version-2-29)

I downloaded libc6_2.34-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/, as described, but when I ran: `sudo dpkg -i libc6_2.34-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb`, it produced the following error:

```
dpkg: regarding libc6_2.34-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb containing libc6:amd64:
 libc6:amd64 breaks fakeroot (<< 1.25.3-1.1ubuntu2~)
  fakeroot (version 1.24-1) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive libc6_2.34-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb (--install):
 installing libc6:amd64 would break fakeroot, and
 deconfiguration is not permitted (--auto-deconfigure might help)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6_2.34-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

How do I solve this? I am a bit of a newb, so preferably without breaking my system

Comment: Do not upgrade libc because of single application, it is very dangerous action. How Stockfish was installed? What is its version? From which PPA/Flatpak/Appimage/Snap/tar?

Comment: I get it from here: https://abrok.eu/stockfish/

It's the linux for modern computers + av2 version that always worked.

I really, really depend on this I'm afraid -_-

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: Just curious what is your CPU model?

Comment: @N0rbert it's an Intel Core i7-4710HQ

Comment: @guiverc I sort of already knew about this, but I really depend on Stockfish running

Comment: It has just happened to me today with Stockfish 15. Same problems. I'm also on Ubuntu 20.04 (the CPU is similar: Intel Core i7-6700HQ). I simply compiled the code and used the exe that was generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be noted that https://abrok.eu/stockfish/ is not official, author clearly says that the packages were compiled with gcc 11.2/mingw 10 on Ubuntu 21.10.
While you are running 20.04 LTS which is older, so has older libc and other core system components.

I see two possible solutions:

- **Official packages from the developer**

  The StockFish package for Ubuntu [lists](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/jammy/stockfish) the following URL as developer's web-site https://stockfishchess.org . So you should visit https://stockfishchess.org/download/linux/ and then download relevant software distribution. For the time of writing it maybe done programmatically as follows:

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  wget -c https://stockfishchess.org/files/stockfish_14.1_linux_x64_avx2.zip
  unzip stockfish_14.1_linux_x64_avx2.zip
  cd stockfish_14.1_linux_x64_avx2
  chmod +x stockfish_14.1_linux_x64_avx2
  ```

  and then run it as `./stockfish_14.1_linux_x64_avx2`.

  Note: it runs even on 18.04 LTS, does not complain about libc.
- **Some third-party PPA**

  Finding [PPA for StockFish is possible](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=stockfish). It will end with for example [StockFish 12.2 deb-package for 20.04 LTS](https://launchpad.net/%7Esavoury1/+archive/ubuntu/games/+packages?field.name_filter=stockfish&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=focal), which may be installed by using below commands:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/games
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install stockfish
  ```

  Note: I'm not sure about AVX2 optimisation here.

  Reverting to default [11.1 version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/stockfish) is possible by using below commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
  sudo ppa-purge ppa:savoury1/games
  ```

Comment: Thank you! I went for the official 14.1 release and now it works :)

Comment: I found that the downloads page only linked to the latest version, whereas [the directory of files](https://stockfishchess.org/files/) lists all available. You can go back through the numbers until you find one that works on your system.

Comment: Stockfish 15 does not work on Ubuntu 20.04 glibc

Comment: I wonder why would an author compile software meant for public use in a bleeding edge toolchain that's incompatible with current systems. One should always use the _oldest_ possible toolchain, so the binary it is compatible with a broader audience.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Stockfish 15 on Ubuntu 20.04. However it's not too difficult to compile from source following the directions at https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish#compiling-stockfish-yourself-from-the-sources

```
cd src
make help
```

then check the latest arch supported, ex. `grep bmi2 /proc/cpuinfo` and make with the appropriate arch:

```
make net 
make build ARCH=x86-64-bmi2
```