# libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_2.30' not found

Tags: 18.04, glibc

I'm trying to run immersed executable and I get the following errors:

> Immersed: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not
> found (required by Immersed)

> Immersed: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_2.30'
> not found (required by Immersed)

Is there a way to upgrade GLIBC or does I have to upgrade Ubuntu to do that?
I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is possible to update glibc when there is a security issue (see [Upgrading glibc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/736208/upgrading-glibc)).

That being said, it seems that for Immersed the best option would be to upgrade your OS version (see https://discord.com/channels/428916969283125268/681876093107699736/996050843314954280)